# How to replace particular values in dataframe column from a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary

So, I have a table of the following manner:

```
Col1     Col2
ABS      45
CDC      23
POP      15
```

Now, I have a dictionary `aa = {'A':'AD','P':'PL','C':'LC'}`. So for the matching key parts only I want the values in the column to change. For the other letters which do not match the dictionary keys should remain the same.

The final table should look like:

```
Col1     Col2
ADBS     45
LCDLC    23
PLOPL    15
```

I am trying to use the following code but it is not working.

```py
df['Col1'].str.extract[r'([A-Z]+)'].map(aa)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['ABS', 'CDC', 'POP'], 
                   'Col2': [45, 23, 15], 
                  })

keys = aa.keys()
df.Col1 = [''.join([aa.get(e) if (e in keys) else e for e in list(ee)]) for ee in df.Col1.tolist()]
df
```

**Output**:

[image]

> ### Unpacking the Condensed List Comprehension

Let us write down the list comprehension in a more readable form. We create a function `do_something` to understand what is happenning in the first part of the list-comprehension. The second part (`for ee in df.Col1.tolist()`) essentially iterates over each row in the column `'Col1'` of the dataframe `df`.

```py
def do_something(x):
    # here x is like 'ABS'
    xx = '.join([aa.get(e) if (e in keys) else e for e in list(x)])
    return xx
df.Col1 = [do_something(ee) for ee in df.Col1.tolist()]
```

#### Unpacking `do_something(x)`

The function `do_something(x)` does the following. It will be easier if you try it with `x = 'ABS'`. The `''.join(some_list)` in `do_something` joins the list produced. The following code block will illustrate that.

```py
x = 'ABS'
print(do_something(x))
[aa.get(e) if (e in keys) else e for e in list(x)]
```

**Output**:

```
ADBS
['AD', 'B', 'S']
```

> #### So what is the core logic?
>
> The following code-block shows you step-by-step how the logic works. Obviously, the `list comprehension` introduced at the beginning of the solution compresses the `nested for loops` into a single line, and hence should be preferred over the following.

```
keys = aa.keys()
packlist = list()
for ee in df.Col1.tolist():
    # Here we iterate over each element of 
    # the dataframe's column (df.Col1)

    # make a temporary list
    templist = list()
    for e in list(ee):
        # here e is a single character of the string ee
        # example: list('ABS') = ['A', 'B', 'S']
        if e in keys:
            # if e is one of the keys in the dict aa
            # append the corresponding value to templist
            templist.append(aa.get(e))
        else:
            # if e is not a key in the dict aa
            # append e itself to templist
            templist.append(e)
    # append a copy of templist to packlist
    packlist.append(templist.copy())

# Finally assign the list: packlist to df.Col1 
# to update the column values
df.Col1 = packlist
```

## References

List and dict comprehensions are some very powerful tools any python programmer would find handy and nifty while coding. They have the ability to neatly compress an otherwise elaborate code-block into merely a line or two. I would suggest that you take a look at the following.

1. [List Comprehensions: `python.org`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
2. [Dict Comprehensions: `python.org`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
3. [List Comprehension in Python: `medium.com`](https://medium.com/better-programming/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b)

Comment: Ok. I will add some explanation in the solution. Is your question about list comprehension? If I write the same thing in nested for loops, would it help more to get clarity of what is happening?

Comment: Yes that would be helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SayantanGhosh Could you please also **`upvote`** the answer? Thank you. P.S. Additional notes added for clarity on the list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful.

Comment: @SayantanGhosh Added a reference section with links to **list** and **dict** `comprehensions`. You may take a look at it. Learning list comprehensions came very handy for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using replace like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['ABS', '45'], ['CDC', '23'], ['POP', '15']], columns=('Col1', 'Col2'))
aa = {'A':'AD','P':'PL','C':'LC'}
pat = "|".join(aa.keys())
df["Col1"].str.replace(pat, lambda x: aa.get(x[0], x[0]))
```

Comment: This is just an example I have given, the dictionary I am using is quite big and it is not possible to write all the values in the parantheses.

Comment: do you mean you can't get ```aa``` dictionary like above?